# 1988 kawasaki ninja 600 only runs on choke crackles bogs dies

Tags: kawasaki, classic

Hello everyone I recently acquired a 1988 kawasaki ninja 600 the bike was in pieces and I reassembled it and got it running the issue I'm having is it will only run on choke I've cleaned the carbs multiple times it will run and drive on choke but randomly bog and the exaust will crackle / backfire and often it will completely die but if I stop and hit the starter it will start immediately back up and hesitantly idle back up to 4k with is what the choke makes it idle at I also replaced the ic ignitor with a known good unit due to a no spark issue I traced to that part. I am at a complete loss any help is appreciated do i just rebuild the carbs again or what. I've done the get it running and spray carb cleaner all over to test for vacuum leaks test and it seems to be all sealed good.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When your cycle will ONLY run on choke, it's a fueling problem, which means there's an issue with the carbs providing fuel or there's not enough fuel getting to the carbs. Could be a float issue or plugged passageways allowing for the idle to work correctly. It all comes back to fuel, though.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds to me like a fuel pump issue or blocked main jets